# How to connect my Java EE app with alfresco

Tags: jakarta-ee, alfresco

I just getting started with Alfresco and i want to know if it's possible to get a connexion throw my java EE application with Alfresco 
thank you

Answer (score 3):

With the following assumption judging your question, yes its possible.

*Assumption : You are building a Java EE application and you want to integrate Alfresco functionalities through your custom built Java EE application.*

There are two ways of doing this,

1. Use **Apache's Chemistry** which connects to Alfresco through CMIS services (Refer: http://chemistry.apache.org/java/opencmis.html).
2. Using **Alfresco's very own REST API**'s (refer: http://docs.alfresco.com/community/pra/1/topics/pra-welcome.html).

**Word of advice beforehand**

- Alfresco have variety of products (Alfresco-One, Alfresco Community Edition, etc).
- Make sure you always refer to the documentation for **which product you are using**.
- Make sure you refer to the **correct version of Alfresco**, there are differences in REST API calls from version to version..
- Last but not the least, make sure **you get the correct understanding of how Alfresco works** (conceptual understanding). Because its a pretty big application which could be confusing when diving in, but could play nasty stuff with the experience.
- Sometimes these documentations would be hard to follow or confusing, **I advice you to follow Jeff Potts** who is one of the leading guy in the Alfresco community. His blog being http://ecmarchitect.com He have some **great articles and most importantly step by step tutorials** for common problems we face in Alfresco.
- I listed these because you've said you are *getting started with Alfresco.*

Answer (score 0):

If WebDAV access is sufficient for your project I can recommend [Sardine](https://github.com/lookfirst/sardine). It's simple, easy to use and well documented. For example listing resources:

```
Sardine sardine = SardineFactory.begin(username, password);

List<DavResource> resources = sardine.list("http://yourdavserver.com/adirectory/");
for (DavResource res : resources) {
    System.out.println(res);
}
```

For more examples, please check the [usage guide](https://github.com/lookfirst/sardine/wiki/UsageGuide).